# How to select and download only specific PDF from a website?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I found some code online that allows you to download all the PDF found from a url and it works, but it fails on the website I need it for. Im trying to download the PDF of the menu for each day of the week and I can't seem to figure out how to narrow it down to only those 7 pdf files.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://calbaptist.edu/dining/alumni-dining-commons"

# Requests URL and get response object
response = requests.get(url)
  
# Parse text obtained
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
  
# Find all hyperlinks present on webpage
links = soup.find_all('a')
  
i = 0
  
# From all links check for pdf link and
# if present download file
for link in links:
    if (".pdf" in link.get('href', [])):
        i += 1
        print("Downloading file: ", i)
  
        # Get response object for link
        response = requests.get(link.get('href'))
  
        # Write content in pdf file
        pdf = open("pdf"+str(i)+".pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(response.content)
        pdf.close()
        print("File ", i, " downloaded")
  
print("All PDF files downloaded")
```

I tried to change the `if-statement` to instead of looking for `.pdf` to look for `/dining/menus-and-hours/adc-menus/`. This gave me an error on the line that gets the responce object for the link.

Comment: `pdf.write(response.content)` <-- You need to **verify** that `response` represents an `application/pdf` file before writing it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `href` values, they are relative and not absolute, so you have to prepend the "base url".

You could also select your elements more specific with [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) like contains something:

```
soup.select('a[href*="/dining/menus-and-hours/adc-menus/"]')
```

or ends with `.pdf`

```
soup.select('a[href$=".pdf"]')
```

May also take a look at [`enumerat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,e in enumerate(soup.select('a[href*="/dining/menus-and-hours/adc-menus/"]'),start=1):
```

Checking content type of reponse header:

```
requests.get('https://calbaptist.edu'+e.get('href')).headers['Content-Type']
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://calbaptist.edu/dining/alumni-dining-commons"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

for i,e in enumerate(soup.select('a[href*="/dining/menus-and-hours/adc-menus/"]'),start=1):
    r = requests.get('https://calbaptist.edu'+e.get('href'))
    if r.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/pdf':
        pdf = open("pdf"+str(i)+".pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(r.content)
        pdf.close()
        print("File ", i, " downloaded")
```